# undefined instruction after upgrading kernel from 4 to 5 on sama5d2 board

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel

I am using a sama5d2 board and I wanted to move from kernel 4 to 5. After I did that, I am getting stuck at the following point:

```
Starting kernel ...

undefined instruction
pc : [<220100a4>]          lr : [<2200338c>]
sp : 2247c450  ip : 2200ffff     fp : 2247b460
r10: 20008000  r9 : 2200ffff     r8 : 2200ffff
r7 : 2247b438  r6 : 2200ffff     r5 : 00000000  r4 : ffffffff
r3 : 00000001  r2 : 2247b438     r1 : 00000030  r0 : 0000006f
Flags: nzCv  IRQs off  FIQs off  Mode SVC_32
Resetting CPU ...
```

My question is, what is the best way to debug this problem?

Comment: Check your toolchain. Verify the built copy of the kernel image on the host to the installed image in NVM and what is loaded for boot. Check your boot procedure that you're loading the complete & validated kernel image. Make sure you're not stepping on the kernel image during boot. Use a JTAG debugger to see what happens after U-Boot passes control. Enable **earlycon** or **earlyprintk** in the kernel.

Comment: Are you sure the kernel you installed supports Cortex A5?